# How to inspect mapped tasks' inputs from reduce tasks in Prefect

Tags: prefect

I'm exploring Prefect's map-reduce capability as a powerful idiom for writing massively-parallel, robust importers of external data.

As an example - very similar to the [X-Files tutorial](https://docs.prefect.io/core/advanced_tutorials/advanced-mapping) - consider this snippet:

```
@task
def retrieve_episode_ids():
    api_connection = APIConnection(prefect.context.my_config)
    return api_connection.get_episode_ids()


@task(max_retries=2, retry_delay=datetime.timedelta(seconds=3))
def download_episode(episode_id):
    api_connection = APIConnection(prefect.context.my_config)
    return api_connection.get_episode(episode_id)


@task(trigger=all_finished)
def persist_episodes(episodes):
    db_connection = DBConnection(prefect.context.my_config)
    ...store all episodes by their ID with a success/failure flag...


with Flow("import_episodes") as flow:
    episode_ids = retrieve_episode_ids()
    episodes = download_episode.map(episode_ids)
    persist_episodes(episodes)
```

The peculiarity of my flow, compared with the simple X-Files tutorial, is that I would like to persist results for *all* the episodes that I have requested, even for the failed ones. Imagine that I'll be writing episodes to a database table as the episode ID decorated with an *is_success* flag. Moreover, I'd like to write all episodes with a single task instance, in order to be able to perform a bulk insert - as opposed to inserting each episode one by one - hence my `persist_episodes` task being a *reduce* task.

The trouble I'm having is in being able to gather the episode ID for the failed downloads from that *reduce* task, so that I can store the failed information in the table under the appropriate episode ID. I could of course rewrite the `download_episode` task with a try/catch and always return an episode ID even in the case of failure, but then I'd lose the automatic retry/failure functionality which is a good deal of the appeal of Prefect.

Is there a way for a *reduce* task to infer the argument(s) of a failed mapped task? Or, could I write this differently to achieve what I need, while still keeping the same level of clarity as in my example?

Answer (score 1):

Mapping over a list preserves the order. This is a property you can use to link inputs with the errors. Check the code I have below, will add more explanation after.

```py
from prefect import Flow, task
import prefect

@task
def retrieve_episode_ids():
    return [1,2,3,4,5]


@task
def download_episode(episode_id):
    if episode_id == 5:
        return ValueError()
    return episode_id


@task()
def persist_episodes(episode_ids, episodes):
    # Note the last element here will be the ValueError
    prefect.context.logger.info(episodes)
    # We change that ValueError into a "fail" message
    episodes = ["fail" if isinstance(x, BaseException) else x for x in episodes]
    # Note the last element here will be the "fail"
    prefect.context.logger.info(episodes)
    result = {}
    for i, episode_id in enumerate(episode_ids):
        result[episode_id] = episodes[i]
    # Check final results
    prefect.context.logger.info(result)
    return

with Flow("import_episodes") as flow:
    episode_ids = retrieve_episode_ids()
    episodes = download_episode.map(episode_ids)
    persist_episodes(episode_ids, episodes)

flow.run()
```

The handling will largely happen in the `persist_episodes`. Just pass the list of inputs again and then we can match the inputs with the failed tasks. I added some handling around identifying errors and replacing them with what you want. Does that answer the question?

Always happy to chat more. You can reach out in the Prefect Slack or Discourse as well.

Comment: This definitely answers the question, thank you. The fact that mapping preserves the order is quite key, glad to learn that today!